# R Shinny conditional widget Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements, widget

I am creating an r shiny app for strength and conditioning coaches that will allow them to select the type of drill, the drill name, and for how long they want to do the drill. I have two of the widgets working but with the code I am using right now the conditional widget is not working and I am getting this error when I try and run the app.

Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$group_ui <- renderUI({
lapply(seq_len(input$num_groups), function(i) {
  fluidRow(
    column(4, selectInput(paste0("DT_", i), "Drill Type:", choices = 
c("Technical", "Tactical", "Transitions"))),
    column(4, uiOutput(paste0("Drill_", i))),
    column(4, sliderInput(paste0("slider_", i), "Time:", min = 1, max = 
40, value = 20))
  )
})
})

observe({
lapply(seq_len(input$num_groups), function(i) {
  output[[paste0("Drill_", i)]] <- renderUI({
    items <- AVERAGE[AVERAGE$`Drill Name` == input[[paste0("DT_", i)]]]
    updateSelectInput(session, paste0("Drill_", i),"Drill Name:", 
choices =  items)
  })
})
})
```

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt97D.png)

I am trying to create a conditional widget that has the selection options populated based on the input of another widget. In the data set, there is a column that has the options for the first widget and a column that has the drill names. when a drill type is selected from the first widget then the second ones selection options should populate with all of the drills that have that drill type.  I am pretty sure the problem is in the last two lines of code.

Comment: please refrain from posting code or data as images, it makes it much harder for people to make use of any reproductible example you can provide.  See the topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: your `items <- AVERAGE[...` is a dataframe. moreover you're trying to update `Drill_i` instead of `DT_i`.

Comment: Stéphane Laurent - 
should I not be calling to the data frame? I thought that I had to to get the Drill names

Answer (score 0):

Drill_i is an output. What you probably want to update is DT_i. Try using the browser() function to stop the execution so you can look at the values. Also, consider using pipes (`%>%`) from the dplyr package. See code below.

```
observe({
  lapply(seq_len(input$num_groups), function(i) {
    output[[paste0("Drill_", i)]] <- renderUI({
      items <- AVERAGE %>%
               filter("Drill Name" == input[[paste0("DT_", i)]]) %>%
               pull("Drill Type")
      updateSelectInput(session, paste0("DT_", i),"Drill Name:", 
      choices =  items)
    })
  })
})
```

I'm not sure this will fix you issue completely. Nevertheless, it should get you closer to the solution. Please consider updating your code to represent a valid minimal example.